# Скрытие одной из фотографий, по клику

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть фотографии

```
<ul id="gallery">
        <li class="loaded">
            <span class="photo-actions">
            <a href="#" class="loaded-remove"><i class="halflings-icon remove"></i></a>
            <a href="#" class="loaded-edit"><i class="halflings-icon pencil"></i></a>
            </span>
            <a rel="example_group" href="/algo/get/get_photo_by_id.php?id=177">
            <img src="/upload/iblock/39c/39c304776af2b1d279a40f4b8cdc45c3.jpg" title="NGUHsvpebho.jpg">
            </a>
    </li>
        <li class="loaded">
            <span class="photo-actions">
            <a href="#" class="loaded-remove"><i class="halflings-icon remove"></i></a>
            <a href="#" class="loaded-edit"><i class="halflings-icon pencil"></i></a>
            </span>
            <a rel="example_group" href="/algo/get/get_photo_by_id.php?id=177">
            <img src="/upload/iblock/39c/39c304776af2b1d279a40f4b8cdc45c3.jpg" title="NGUHsvpebho.jpg">
            </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

У каждой фотографии есть иконка удалить

```
 <a href="#" class="loaded-remove"><i class="halflings-icon remove"></i></a>
```

Хочу сделать чтобы при нажатии на нее, скрывалась именно та фотографии, у которой эта иконка.

Скрипт скрывает все фотографии

```
$("#gallery .loaded .photo-actions .loaded-remove").click(function () {
    $(this).hide('slow');
return true;
});
```

а как можно сделать, чтобы именно конкретная скрывалась?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка не воспроизводится. Вот ваш код (заменил только адреса картинок): http://jsfiddle.net/NtU3g/. А вот он же с минимальными изменениями (работает так как вам нужно): http://jsfiddle.net/NtU3g/1/.